# Generating attribute methods - any bad side effects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In rails, if I want to override an attribute method, eg. a setter, or getter etc, I might need the instance method to be defined.

However, activerecord does not define attribute methods until an instance is first synchronized.

This can be seen in:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
end

MyModel.attribute_methods_generated? # => false
MyModel.instance_method(:a_db_column)
  # => NameError Exception: undefined method `a_db_column' for class `MyModel'
MyModel.new # implicitly calls define_attribute_methods
# MyModel.define_attribute_methods # can also use this instead of MyModel.new
MyModel.attribute_methods_generated? # => true
MyModel.instance_method(:a_db_column)
#<UnboundMethod: MyModel(#<Module:0x000000030a20a0>)#__temp__>
```

Is there any problem that could occur in calling `define_attribute_methods` early? Even doing something like:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  define_attribute_methods 
  # is there any code here which might cause problems?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the instance method to be defined ? From what I understand, you're trying to add/override an instance method, so when you call this method, `define_attribute_methods` would have been called since an instance was created.

Tell me if I get you wrong.

Comment: don't try to understand why I am doing it, I want to write a gem. If you are defining a method, you might want `oldmethod = instance_method(:a_db_column); def a_db_column;oldmethod.bind(self).call;end;def another_method;oldmethod.bind(self).call;end;oldmethod = instance_method(:a_db_column); def a_db_column;oldmethod.bind(self).call;end;`

Comment: Ok. Sorry I cannot be of help then.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you provided it seems like you want to patch the methods generated by ActiveRecord on a model.  Instead of triggering ActiveRecord's method generation, why not patch the define_attribute_methods to call your patching method after it has completed?